# Why promise always returns same data over and again?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I am running into trouble and it seems like promise is caching variable.

```
const num = Math.random()
const fun = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(num))
// Now, calling fun again and again, it gives me same result
await fun()
await fun()
await fun()
```

If I put use it like below. Then it works as expected:

```
const fun = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(Math.random()))
```

How can I solve this problem using constant variable as in preceding example?

Comment: you **cannot** solve this by using a constant variable, because the entire point of a constant is that it never changes.  What is the use case that you have which causes you to not be able to use the second form?

Comment: Yes, a promise caches the value you resolve it with, but that's not your problem here. `fun()` does create a new promise on every call as expected, it's just that you resolve all of them with the same **constant** `num` value.

Comment: to be fair, you could use a constant *function* that calls the `Math.random()` function and returns the result, rather than a constant *variable* that stores the return of the call, but that seems unnecessary here.

Comment: I assume this is either to try out promises, or that this snippet is not your full/actual code you are making, but just in case: It makes no sense at all here to use Promises. `Math.random()` isn't asynchronous so you can just return its value immediately. (But _if_ you want it to always resolve to a specific value like you do here, you can also use `Promise.resolve(Math.random())`.)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are generating a random number **once**, then you return that same number from the "fun" promise function. In the second example you generate a **new** random number **every time** you call "fun".

Answer (score 0):

"How can I solve this problem using constant variable as in preceding example?"

You cannot. If you use a *constant* variable, you will get a *constant* result. To get a different result you need to generate a new number every time, as in the second example you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have to watch carefully how function & variable works.

- Example 1: In `num` constant variable you call the function `random()` that returns a floating-point and stores it as `num` value.
  Then you call `fun()` that returns a Promise and resolves an already INITIALIZED value from `num`

```js
    const num = Math.random() // <= HERE!
    const fun = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(num))
    // Now, calling fun again and again, it gives me same result
    await fun()
    await fun()
    await fun()
```

- Example 2: Again when you call `fun()` you get the resolved value in the Promise. But, this time is not an already initialized value from a variable. You are calling `random()` method each time a `new Promise` is setted.

```js
  const fun = () => new Promise(resolve => 
                                       resolve(Math.random())) // <= HERE!
```